# Clojure - Delete Items from a Vector to Represent Dealing from a Deck of Cards

Tags: clojure

I have a vector of vectors that I'm using to represent a deck of cards:

```
[["A" "D"] ["K" "H"] ["K" "C"] ["K" "S"] ["K" "D"] ["Q" "H"] ["Q" "C"] ["Q" "S"]
 ["Q" "D"] ["J" "H"] ["J" "C"] ["J" "S"] ["J" "D"] ["T" "H"] ["T" "C"] ["T" "S"]
 ["T" "D"] ["9" "H"] ["9" "C"] ["9" "S"] ["9" "D"] ["8" "H"] ["8" "C"] ["8" "S"]
 ["8" "D"] ["7" "H"] ["7" "C"] ["7" "S"] ["7" "D"] ["6" "H"] ["6" "C"] ["6" "S"]
 ["6" "D"] ["5" "H"] ["5" "C"] ["5" "S"] ["5" "D"] ["4" "H"] ["4" "C"] ["4" "S"]
 ["4" "D"] ["3" "H"] ["3" "C"] ["3" "S"] ["3" "D"] ["2" "H"] ["2" "C"] ["2" "S"]
 ["2" "D"]]
```

At some point, I would like to "deal" some cards and have those cards removed from the deck.

It's also fine if you'd like to tell me to use a seq and actually my original was a seq of vectors, so it doesn't matter either way to me.

I do know that I would probably like to create an atom of "remaining-deck" and delete the items from this seq or vector.

I'm planning to open-source this, and this is the pertinent part of the code:

```
(def suits ["H" "C" "S" "D"])
(def ranks ["A" "K" "Q" "J" "T" "9" "8" "7" "6" "5" "4" "3" "2"])

(def deck (for [x ranks
                y suits]
            [x y]))


;; alternative deck that creates vector:

(def deck2 (vec (for [x ranks
                y suits]
            [x y])))

;;Another way to do it: While it's fine if I have a sequence of string pairs, I'd rather use vectors of vectors because I think destructuring will work better plus I think it'll be consistent across the program. 

(def deck3 (for [x ranks
                y suits]
            (str x y)))


(def hand [(rand-nth deck) (rand-nth deck)])

(def full-hand (concat board hand))
```

It looks like I could concatenate subvecs via using some .indexOf functions and tossing it into an atom, but I can't help but think that this is hacky and a Lisp should be able to do better than this. I seriously can't find any good information on this anywhere. I am aware of remove and filter, but those don't appear to be doing anything but throwing errors.

---

EDIT: Why the downvote? I'm simply trying to update the deck after dealing the cards.

Thus if I was representing a smaller deck:

```
[["A" "D"] ["K" "H"] ["K" "C"] ["K" "S"] ["K" "D"] ["Q" "H"] ["Q" "C"] ["Q" "S"]]
```

Then after an update from (ex: player is deal ["Q" "S"] ["Q" "C"], the remaining deck should look like:

```
[["A" "D"] ["K" "H"] ["K" "C"] ["K" "S"] ["K" "D"] ["Q" "H"]]
```

So that there are no shared hands or duplicate cards during the rest of the deal.

Comment: What's your question?

Comment: Your updated question still doesn't have an actual question in it. At the very least a good question should contain a sentence with a question mark at the end of it! For example (and I'm guessing here), "What is an idiomatic way creating a data structure to represent a deck of cards?" Or maybe, "How do I synchronize the state of this deck among multiple threads?" Or maybe even "How do I use atoms with a vector of vectors?" You've given background to your question but no question.

Comment: I showed a "before" and and "after" picture of what I want. I left it slightly open-ended because there are multiple ways to do things in Clojure and I honestly was not sure if a vec of vecs was the best way. Had I asked specifically for a vec, I would have only got vec answers which I didn't want to happen. Notice how I chose an answer that uses sets? Why do you automatically assume a Clojure question deals with multi-threading and why would you assume I am only looking for atoms when there are so many other "stateful" things available?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not sure if I understood your question properly, but whatever I have gathered I would represent the deck as a set wrapped in a atom and on each hand play update the atom.

```
(def suits ["H" "C" "S" "D"])
(def ranks ["A" "K" "Q" "J" "T" "9" "8" "7" "6" "5" "4" "3" "2"])

(def deck (atom  (->> (for [x ranks
                            y suits]
                        [x y])
                      (into #{}))))

(defn hand []
  (-> (rand-int (count @deck))
      (drop @deck)
      (first)))

(defn play-hand []
  (swap! deck clojure.set/difference #{(hand)}))

(play-hand)
```

Comment: Looks like you pretty much nailed it. Updated the deck and that will be enough to get me on my way. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I know this had an answer accepted already, but are you convinced you want to introduce state here?  I would consider passing through `deck` as a parameter to `hand` and the like.  What happens when you want to deal your hands in parallel?

Comment: No, not convinced that I want to introduce state, but it seemed to make some sense since this is going to end up being a heads-up player -vs- bot game. I'm just not sure how else I would ensure that no cards are duplicated although I guess I could lazily pop off the next card from a pre-shuffled deck. I would definitely be interested in seeing a "stateless" version of this. I don't think parallelism is needed here, plus, that whole thing about crawling before running.